# Android: Adding a view. Different screen size and densities

Tags: android, imageview, screen

I´m trying to add a ImageView (a symbol) each time the user touch on a Imageview (A car picture) in order to let the user indicate where the car has a damage. Then I send the points to a remote server so I can get the points when the acitivity is opened again. It works properly in the specific device that set the points, but if you get the points using another device whith different screen size and resolution, obviously, the symbols are not OK.
Is there any way to scale points and ImageView in order to make it possible? I mean, how could I make that, if you indicate there is a damage in the front/left door of the car, the symbol was always there when running the app in different screen sizes?

Code I´m using:

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                final RelativeLayout urLayoutId=(RelativeLayout)    findViewById(R.id.RelativeCoche);
                final ImageView imv=new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    imv.setImageResource(R.drawable.info);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(Math.round(event.getX()),
                    Math.round(event.getY()), 0, 0); 
                    imv.setLayoutParams(params);
                return true;
             }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to do is to include different images with the proper densities in the corresponding drawable-xxxx folder. Look at the last section of this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) for more information.

Comment: Hello Emmanuel, Thank you for your answer. I´m afraid I have to improve my English so I will say just what I need. I have a car picture and I need to add a symbol where the car has a damage. It works in my device and I send de points where the events happens to a remote server. If I try to paint the symbols in my tablet using the points I send from my cell phone they are not in the correct place because the image of the car and the screen size are bigger. I hope I make me understand quite better now. Sorry again form my English and thank you in advance.

Comment: I still think you will need to place different copies of your image in the corresponding drawable folder. For example, if you are targeting a hdpi device you need to place a picture on the drawable-hdpi folder. Then the system will automatically select that version of the image when you call R.drawable.my_image.